# Adding sum to each element in an object and return top N key/value pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have an object array of key/value pairs where the values are another set of key/value pairs where all the values are numerical. I'd like to sum up all of the values for each key and then add a new element for each key with that aggregated sum. Once I have that, I'd like to be able to then select the top 5 main keys in the object array based on the aggregated sum value.

My data (object) looks like this

```
{
   "Napkins":{
      "N/A":200,
      "No supply":100,
      "More than 1 wk":150,
      "1 week or less":50
   },
   "Plates":{
      "N/A":800
   },
   "Forks":{
      "N/A":100,
      "No supply":100,
      "More than 1 wk":50,
      "1 week or less":50
   },
   "Knives":{
      "N/A":300,
      "No supply":100
   }
}
```

I'd like to be able to add a `total` value to sum the values for each primary outer key so that my final object looks as such:

```
{
   "Napkins":{
      "N/A":200,
      "No supply":100,
      "More than 1 wk":150,
      "1 week or less":50,
      "total":500
   },
   "Plates":{
      "N/A":800,
      "total":800
   },
   "Forks":{
      "N/A":100,
      "No supply":100,
      "More than 1 wk":50,
      "1 week or less":50,
      "total":300
   },
   "Knives":{
      "N/A":300,
      "No supply":100,
      "total":400
   }
}
```

Once I have that, I'm hoping to be able to easily sort the array by `total` and slice it by top 5 or an arbitrary number **n** to only return those **n** items so that I can then loop through them and create a d3 visualization for each of the top **n** items. My only problem is getting the final array needed with the top items.

**EDIT:** I was able to write a nested loop to add a `total` field. Not sure if there is a better way to do this but now looking to understand the best way to access slice and access the key/value elements with the top 5 `total` values. This is the code I have for looping through the original object:

```
for (const item of Object.values(processed_data)){
    let sum = Object.values(item).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);
    item.total = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the object data structure, it's not possible to sort the values as such. But, I was able to limit the number of entries to `N` in the below code:

```js
const data = {
  "Napkins": {
    "N/A": 200,
    "No supply": 100,
    "More than 1 wk": 150,
    "1 week or less": 50
  },
  "Plates": {
    "N/A": 800
  },
  "Forks": {
    "N/A": 100,
    "No supply": 100,
    "More than 1 wk": 50,
    "1 week or less": 50
  },
  "Knives": {
    "N/A": 300,
    "No supply": 100
  }
};

const getTopN = 3;
Object.values(data).forEach(reasons => {
  // Alternatively, d3.sum(Object.values(reasons)) also works
  reasons.total = Object.values(reasons).reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0);
}, {});

// Get the value from the N^th threshold
const threshold = Object.values(data)
  .map(reasons => reasons.total)
  .sort()
  .reverse()[getTopN - 1];

const topN = Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([type, reasons]) => reasons.total >= threshold)
  .reduce((obj, [type, reasons]) => {
    obj[type] = reasons;
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(topN);
```

---

Alternatively, can you change the data structure:

```js
const data = {
  "Napkins": {
    "N/A": 200,
    "No supply": 100,
    "More than 1 wk": 150,
    "1 week or less": 50
  },
  "Plates": {
    "N/A": 800
  },
  "Forks": {
    "N/A": 100,
    "No supply": 100,
    "More than 1 wk": 50,
    "1 week or less": 50
  },
  "Knives": {
    "N/A": 300,
    "No supply": 100
  }
};

const getTopN = 3;
const arrayData = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([item, reasons]) => ({
    item,
    total: Object.values(reasons).reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0),
    reasons
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => b.total - a.total)
  .slice(0, getTopN);
console.log(arrayData);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. However - I'm now running into issues when I try to use the code I have to visualize it in d3 because I can't seem to get it in the right data structure. Alternative is to to change my code for the visualization to work with the output above but changing the data seems easier. Is there a way I can easily get the data above into the following array form for each item in `arrayData`: ```0: {reason: "N/A", value:200} 1: {reason: "No supply", value:100} 2: {reason: "More than 1 wk", value: 150} 3: {reason: "1 week or less", value: 50} 4: {reason: "total", value: 500 } ```